# PHP PDO mysql prepared statment and join

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a question. 
I have the following query:

```
$query = "select * from module,bloc where module.id_bloc = ?";
```

I tried to bind the value so I did:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, "bloc.id_bloc");
```

But, when I test I don't get any result on my browser. 
It's weird because when I replace directly inside like the following code:

```
$query = "select * from module,bloc where module.id_bloc = bloc.id_bloc";
```

I get the the right result on my browser.

Could someone explain to me why it doesn't work when I am doing a `bindValue`?

Comment: This is not a situation to use parameter binding. This `"select * from module,bloc where module.id_bloc = bloc.id_bloc";` is the correct form.

Comment: I would suggest doing the latter as a join `SELECT * FROM module INNER JOIN bloc ON module.id_bloc = bloc.id_bloc`

Comment: [You can bins string and numeric literals only](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#bindable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Simple curiosity, could it be possible to use parameter binding ?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @e4c5 How come?  Why would you not want to use Prepared Statements here?

Comment: @johnny this is a join not passing a value for a column

Comment: @e4c5 Oh.  Thanks.  I see why it doesn't make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work because, when bound, a string will be quoted. (Or, for all intents and purposes, work as if it were quoted, however PDO may handle it behind the scenes.) Then, your query is interpreted as:

```
select * from module,bloc where module.id_bloc = 'bloc.id_bloc'
```

That is: It will be interpreted as a literal string, rather than a reference to a table column, and will obviously not give you the expected result. There is no need for binding it to begin with.

If, for some reason, you need to run a query with a variable table/column name from an unsafe source, you will have to manually format/sanitize it; [see here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#identifiers) for an example of how to do it.